# Shift Cipher wrongly shifting some characters

Tags: java, encryption, decode, shift, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to use a shift cipher to decode a message. Some of my characters are translating fine but other are not. I cannon figure out what the issue is.

```
public class ShiftCipher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(cipher("F30MDAAFEMA1MI0EF0D9", 14));
}

static String cipher(String msg, int shift){
    String characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
    String DecryptedMessege = "";
    String DecryptedChar = "";
    int trueShift;
    boolean in = false; //Debugging
    for(int x = 0; x < msg.length(); x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < characters.length(); y++ ) {
            if (msg.charAt(x) == characters.charAt(y)){
              if (y+shift <= characters.length()){
                trueShift = y + shift;
                in = true; //Debugging
              }
              else {
                trueShift = shift - (characters.length() - y);
                in = false; //Debugging
              }

            DecryptedChar = new StringBuilder().append(characters.charAt(trueShift)).toString(); 
            System.out.println(DecryptedChar + " " + in + " " + trueShift); //Debugging                 
            }
        }
            DecryptedMessege = DecryptedMessege + DecryptedChar;
    }
    return DecryptedMessege;
}
}
```

Some early letter are being wrongly shifted off by -1. The output should read "THE ROOTS OF WESTERN" but instead reads "TGD ROOTS OE WDSTDRN".

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo `%` (remainder by int division): modulo 4 would count 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Instead of if-then-else the following is easier.

```
          trueShift = (y + shift) % characters.length();
```

Or if y+shift might be negative (then trueShift would become negative too), better:

```
          int n = characters.length();
          trueShift = (y + shift + n) % n;
```

In your else part `trueShift` was not symmetric(injective, not bijective): decrypt(encrypt(s)) != s. If 0,1,2,3 is mapped to 0,1,1,0 there is a problem.

---

```
static String cipher(String msg, int shift){
    String characters = "01234556789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
    int n = characters.length();
    StringBuilder decryptedMessage = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = 0; x < msg.length(); x++) {
        char ch = msg.charAt(x);
        int y = characters.indexOf(ch);
        if (y != -1) {
            int trueShift = (y + shift + n) % n;
            ch = characters.charAt(trueShift);
        }
        decryptedMessage.append(ch);
    }
    return decryptedMessage.toString();
}
```

Comment: You've done a great job in simplifying my code and preventing future bugs, thanks! Unfortunately I also had an extra 5 in my characters string. I've implemented both solutions and the code works as intended.